# 2002 Volkswagen VW Beetle Turbo S Monsoon dash radio not ejecting CD

Tags: vw, manual-transmission, audio, beetle

I have a 2002 Volkswagen VW Beetle Turbo S (2-door hatchback, 5-speed) with a Monsoon radio in the dashboard. When I bought it there was a CD stuck in the player on the radio, and I've been unable to remove it since. How do I remove the CD from the player? If that's not possible, is there a way to purchase a replacement radio and install it?

Answer (score 1):

Disconnect the + cable from the battery and leave it disconnected for 10 minutes. When you re-connect the cable, the CD may pop out on its own. If not, press the eject button. If it still doesn't eject, press and hold the eject button for 30 seconds.

If none of the above are any help and you want to replace the unit, you need a Monsoon radio removal tool, which you may be able to find online by searching.

Comment: Before disconnecting power, make sure you have your [VW Radio Code](https://gunthervwdelray.com/where-is-the-vw-radio-code-located.htm) in case the radio comes back in Safe Mode.